# How does the Value property of TOptions work for IOptions in Core?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I am using the Interface [IOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptions-1?view=aspnetcore-2.0) in Core 2.0:

```
public interface IOptions<out TOptions> where TOptions : class, new()
```

And in my Startup.cs I can wire it [up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options),

```
// Example #1: Basic options
// Register the ConfigurationBuilder instance which MyOptions binds against.
services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);

private readonly MyOptions _options;

_options = optionsAccessor.Value;
```

What I want to know is how does the Framework know what Value is supposed to be?  Where is "Value" assigned?  It's not the same as value in a property, it appears.  Here Value is a whole class reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking the depth implementation of `Options`, you could download [Options](https://github.com/aspnet/Options), and debug the project.

> how does the Framework know what Value is supposed to be?

While you configure the `Options`, you have passed the type by `services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration)` , the `MyOptions` will passed into generic type `TOptions`.

> It's not the same as value in a property, it appears. Here Value is a whole class reference.

Tha `Value` is `TOptions` type which is returned by [OptionsManager](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/70e538699840a8e1e20ca868e0b1a01ae5ff250d/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/OptionsManager.cs#L26).

```
public TOptions Value
    {
        get
        {
            return Get(Options.DefaultName);
        }
    }
```

> Where is "Value" assigned?

`Value` will be configured by [ConfigureNamedOptions](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/edc21af4166574ecd45d8f8dbd381dfec044f367/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/ConfigureNamedOptions.cs#L40) and created by [OptionsFactory](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/e14ed1421c1bc6b233b9042485446cf2fcbbacf9/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/OptionsFactory.cs#L28), then you could access it by `OptionsManager`.